# Mapping SNMP ASN.1 to C++ Datatypes

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp, snmp4j

I am adding SNMP EtherLike MIB variables to our existing SNMP C++ codebase and doing it for very first time.

The difficulty I am facing is understanding the data types of MIB variables and map it to C++ data types - for example **dot3StatsIndex** MIB variable syntax is **InterfaceIndex** so what is it equivalent data type in C++.

Since I am implementing for very first time or rather is in learning phase - please let me know what are the different ASN.1 data types and whether the types all are listed above and how they are mapped to C++ datatypes?

Also how to derive from RFC the data type of the MIB variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just follow the type inheritance chain, you end up with a base SNMP type which should map to the types you have.

For `InterfaceIndex`, see from which MIB it's imported (it's `IF-MIB`):

```
IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, OBJECT-IDENTITY,
    Integer32, Counter32, Counter64, mib-2, transmission
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    MODULE-COMPLIANCE, OBJECT-GROUP
        FROM SNMPv2-CONF
    TruthValue
        FROM SNMPv2-TC
    ifIndex, InterfaceIndex
        FROM IF-MIB;
```

Then find its definition which should reference a base type (it's `Integer32` which probably maps to `ASN1_INT`).

```
InterfaceIndex ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    DISPLAY-HINT "d"
    STATUS       current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A unique value, greater than zero, for each interface or ...
        network management system to the next re-initialization."
    SYNTAX       Integer32 (1..2147483647)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my C++ SNMP Agent, I wrote something like the following (unfortunately the actual source code is no longer available to me, and I'm sure there were many more options, but you get the idea):

```cpp
using varbind_val_t = std::variant<
   
   // ASN.1 INTEGER, SMIv2 Integer32
   int32_t,
   
   // ASN.1 OCTET STRING
   std::string,
   
   // ASN.1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER
   oid_t,
   
   // RFC4001 InetAddressType (TextualConvention)
   IpAddress::Type, // enum saying IPv4 or IPv6
   
   // RFC4001 InetAddress (TextualConvention)
   IpAddress,       // can be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
   
   // SMIv2 IpAddress
   ipv4_t,
   
   // ASN.1 MacAddress (TextualConvention)
   mac_address_t,
   
   // SMIv2 Counter32/Gauge32/TimeTicks/Unsigned32
   uint32_t,
   
   // SMIv2 Counter64
   uint64_t
>;
```

When building or receiving a PDU, the relevant visitors for this variant would encode or decode the wire representation of the given value from a value of the C++ type given above. Sometimes that was a very thin wrapper (an integer is an integer!) and sometimes it required a little more work (oid_t needed unwrapping). This was very fast and flexible. The point is that the mapping is entirely up to you — try to pick types that have the same range of possible values, otherwise you could lose information somewhere along the way. But there is no "the" mapping of C++ types to ASN.1 or SMIv2 types.

Any *textual conventions* like `InterfaceIndex` are not really types, but clues to SNMP managers as to how to represent certain fields. For those not included in the above list as special cases, I simply used the actual underlying type which is, in this case, as Ilya showed, `Integer32`. You can read the MIBs to track down what these things really mean (or use a manager like [iReasoning](http://www.ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml) which does a rather good job of telling you).

You should refer to the relevant specifications to determine what types you need to support:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4001

Comment: Dear anonymous editor: you scared me for a moment! I've since gained access to the real code, so I've checked it and it appears I merely introduced this "bug" while recreating a simple version for SO. For ASN.1 TimeTicks I actually used a type `asn_timeticks_t`, which is a strong alias for `uint32_t`, and for SMIv2 Counter32 I used a type `asn_counter_t` which is a strong alias for... `uint32_t`. Phew! Thanks for your change.